# Explain Ruby Commify large integer method

Tags: ruby, regex

I found this snippet online and the purpose is to commify any number including numbers with decimals ... 99999999 => 99,999,999.  I can see that it uses regex but I am confused by "$1.reverse, $2"

```
def commify(n)
  n.to_s =~ /([^\.]*)(\..*)?/
  int, dec = $1.reverse, $2 ? $2 : ""
  while int.gsub!(/(,|\.|^)(\d{3})(\d)/, '\1\2,\3')
  end
  int.reverse + dec
end
```

Can anyone explain what is going on in this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$1`, `$2`, `$3` ... are Perl legacy. They are [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) variables, that is, they capture the groups inside the regular expression.

A named group is indicated by parentheses. So, the first capture group matches `([^\.])`, which is any non dot character, and `(\..*)` matches a dot character `\.` and any other characters after it.

Note that the second group is optional, so in the line below you have the ternary expression `$2 ? $2 : ""`, which is a crypty-ish way to get either the value of the capture of a blank string.

The `int, dec = $1, $2_or_blank_string` is a [parallel assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html). Ruby supports assigning more than one variable at once, it's not different than doing `int = $1.reversed` then `dec = $2` So `int` now holds the integer part (reversed) and `dec` the decimal part of the number. We are interested in the first one for now.

The next empty `while` does a string substitution. The method [gsub!](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000824) replaces all occurences of the regular expression for the value in the seconf argument. But it returns `nil` if no change happened, which ends the `while`.

The `/(,|\.|^)(\d{3})(\d)/` expression matches:

1. `(,|\.|^)` A comma, a point or the beginning of the string
2. `(\d{3})` Three digits
3. `(\d)` A fourth digit

Then replaces it for `\1\2,\3`. The `\n` in a string substitution mean the nth capture group, just as the `$n` variables do. So, it basically does: *if I have four digits, just add a comma after the third one. Repeat until no group of four digits is found*

Then, just reverse the integer part again and append the decimal part.

Answer (score 5):

`n.to_s =~ /([^\.]*)(\..*)?/` takes the number as a string and stores everything before the decimal point (or simply everything if there is no decimal point) in `$1` and everything after and including it in `$2`.

`int, dec = $1.reverse, $2 ? $2 : ""` stores the reverse of `$1` in `int` and `$2`, or `""` if `$2` is `nil`, in `dec`. In other words `int` now contains the part before the decimal point reversed and `dec` contains the part after the point (not reversed).

The next line inserts a comma every three places into `int`. So by reversing `int` again we get the original integral part of the number with commas inserted every three places from the end. Now we add `dec` again at the end and get the original number with commas at the right places.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
class Integer
  def commify
    self.to_s.gsub(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/,'\1,')
  end
end
```

Then you can do `12345678.commify` and get the string `12,345,678`

And here's one that handles floating point numbers:

```
class Float
  def commify
    self.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d\d\d)(?=\d)(?!\d*\.)/,'\1,').reverse
  end
end
```